# How can I get this script to check every file in the directory BUT not record each individual check?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory

I've been tweaking this script I use for work to try and make it more user friendly to people besides myself. Here's the snippet that's giving me a bit of trouble.

```
def depdelete(path):

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('.exe'):
                os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
                print('Dep Files have been deleted from' + path)
                with open(completeName, 'a') as ddr:
                    ddr.write('Dep Files have been deleted from' + path + '. \n')
            else:
                print('No Dep Files found in' + path)
                with open(completeName, 'a') as ddr:
                    ddr.write('No Further Dep Files found in' + path + '. \n')
```

Now, the script works as intended. Files are deleted and recorded correctly. However, in its current state the Else statement runs for every file in the path, resulting in repeated entries of "No Further Dep Files found in...".

I'd like to change this so that it checks each file, but after checking the whole file, only records one instance of "No Further Dep Files found in..."

Basically, how can I make this *check* every file in the directory, but only record "No Further Dep Files found in..." once, after each file has been checked.

Kind of blanking right now, with a "on the tip of my toungue" feeling. Tips?

Comment: file or folder? You manage to confuse me - you want to print "no Dep.." after you finish to scan each folder?

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag instead.

```
def depdelete(path):

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            found = False              # Add a boolean as flag, reset each iteration
            if f.endswith('.exe'):
                found = True           # Set the flag so "No further..." will not be triggered
                os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
                print('Dep Files have been deleted from' + path)
                with open(completeName, 'a') as ddr:
                    ddr.write('Dep Files have been deleted from' + path + '. \n')
            if not found:              # check the flag
                print('No Dep Files found in' + path)
                with open(completeName, 'a') as ddr:
                    ddr.write('No Further Dep Files found in' + path + '. \n')
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to only need a bit of restructuring.

```
def depdelete(path):

    wereThereAnyDepFiles = False

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for f in files:
            if f.endswith('.exe'):
                os.remove(os.path.join(path, f))
                print('Dep Files have been deleted from' + path)
                with open(completeName, 'a') as ddr:
                    ddr.write('Dep Files have been deleted from' + path + '. \n')
                wereThereAnyDepFiles = True

    if not wereThereAnyDepFiles:
        print("No Dep files found in "+path)
```

Below, what is written to the file suggests that you'd like this to indicate that the end of the check has been reached and you can find no more *.exe* files. Using this assumption, it would be best to place the statement outside the *if* block as I have done below. If I have misunderstood your intent, placing the statement inside the *if* block should achieve what you need.

```
    with open(completeName, 'a') as ddr:
        ddr.write('No Further Dep Files found in'+path+'. \n')
```